# Wasabi Wallet 2.0 coin control. How secure / private are sent coins now?

Tags: client, wasabi-wallet, coin-control

I have a wallet which contains several small coins each with a different level of privacy (Coin Join rounds) which generated in the Wasabi 1.1

I wish to send an amount which I would like to remain as high private. Now there is no coin control how can I be sure that the most mixed coins are used rather than ones that are unmixed in my wallet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish to send an amount which I would like to remain as high private.

If that is truly your goal, then just use the wallet normally. **From a privacy point of view there were significant improvements to the send process:**

There are 3 kinds of coins in your wallet:

- private: coins reached your anonscore target
- semi-private: coins those reached at least anonscore 2
- non-private: anonscore 1 coins

When your wallet is in a half-mixed state,

1. then Wasabi 2.0 will first try to make the transaction from your private stash.
2. If it cannot, then it'll try to combine your private and
   semi-private stash.
3. If it still cannot make a transaction, then
   it'll pop up an option for you to select the clusters that you want
   to make the transaction from. This is a more advanced form of coin
   control, in the sense that you aren't selecting individual coins
   here anymore, but you're selecting a cluster of coins, identified
   though labels, created by intra-wallet blockchain analysis:

[image]

For completeness it must be also noted that, you can still view your coins and selectively spend them by clicking CTRL+C+D.

Comment: 1 and 2 are useless/harmful if you consolidate coinjoined utxos or associate non-coinjoined utxo with coinjoined ones in a transaction. This also affects the privacy of others who participated in coinjoin.

Comment: As stated in the answer, 1 and 2 only happens when the tx can be made solely from private UTXOs. If the tx can be made only by involving non-coinjoined coins, then the user is required to do cluster control.

Comment: @nopara73: I've edited your answer to remove the insult, leaving your response to the comment intact. Just to set some expectations: we don't condone insults and unsubstantiated accusations here. People can be skeptical of your product without being treated as enemies. Please engage with content, do not disparage other users. If you see egregious errors in other people's content about your product where it amounts to misrepresentation, raise a flag and we'll look at it.

Comment: Although I don't think remarking the account not being a real one classifies as an insult, I do think using the flag button would had been more appropriate. I'll do that next time!

Answer (score 1):

> I have a wallet which contains several small coins each with a different level of privacy (Coin Join rounds) which generated in the Wasabi 1.1

There is a workaround for using coin control in Wasabi 2.0. Press [Ctrl + C + D](https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/pull/8096), select coins based on amount, anon, labels and send it to an address.

[image: coincontrol]

> I wish to send an amount which I would like to remain as high private. Now there is no coin control how can I be sure that the most mixed coins are used rather than ones that are unmixed in my wallet ?

All coins are public in bitcoin's UTXO set. [Privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy) could mean different things for users in each transaction. It is the ability to seclude some information. Some users may not prefer spending coinjoined UTXO when sending BTC to an exchange directly because its easy to identify if it was used in a coinjoin round coordinated by zkSNACKs. Wallet could have different types of coins: LN channel close, mining rewards, non-KYC sats, donations, salary etc.

As I shared above, you can use the workaround to select a coin for the transaction (although list doesn't have txid and vout) or trust the algorithm to select coins for you. Consolidating multiple coinjoined UTXO from a round in a transaction either manually or using coin selection algorithm could affect your privacy and others who participated in the round. Its easier to assume all the coins would belong to one entity.

<sub>Disclaimer: zkSNACKs coordinator would [censor](https://blog.wasabiwallet.io/zksnacks-blacklisting-update/) some coins based on blacklist shared by Chainalysis</sub>

Comment: Beware, this answer is from a sockpuppet created with a specific agenda: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113193/how-does-dumplings-work/113194#comment128995_113193

Comment: @nopara73 This is the second time you have falsely accused me of being a sockpuppet. You should respond to my answer if anything wrong is mentioned else I would request the moderators to look in this.

Comment: Hi @nopara73, it's not clear to me how you came to this conclusion. If you disagree with the content of this answer please engage with the content instead of attacking other users.

Comment: @Murch explained here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113193/how-does-dumplings-work?noredirect=1#comment130151_113193